# Clearing a DB call after you close modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

On my about the artist page when you click on the words button, and the will open a modal that gets information from a DB. Right now when you click on one artist button, close the modal, and then click on another artist both artist information will pop up. What I am  trying to do is make sure the information only shows one artist at a time. I'm not sure if there is an issue with my ajax, or my model.

[Here](http://www.arttreeoflife.com/Site/artist) is a link to my live site now

**Model**

```
    <?php 


class Artist_get_model extends CI_Model {
    function getData() {
        // $query = $this->db->get_where("artist_content", array(" " => $page));
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from artist_content");
        return $query;
    }
// FIRST LAST NAME 
// MODEL CHANGES 
// SELECT * from artist_content" where lastname = 
    function modalData($lastname) {

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM artist_content WHERE last_name = '$lastname'");
        return $query;
        // return $lastname;
    }
}
?>
```

**PHP Artist Page**

```
               <?php  
           // echo $query->num_rows();
           echo '<div class="container">';
           echo '<div style="margin-top: 13%;" class=" artistHeader page-header">';
           echo '<h1>Meet the artist</h1>';
           echo '</div>';
           echo '</div>';

           echo '<div class="panel panel-default profile">';
           echo ' <div class="panel-body">';
           echo '<div class="container-fluid">';
           echo '<div class="row">';
           for( $i = 0 ; $i < $query->num_rows() ; $i++ ){
          $row = $query->row_array($i);
           // echo $row['workLink_img2'];



           // for()
          // echo '<div class="row"';
          echo '<div id="noPadding" class="col-md-4">';
          echo '<div class="thumbnail noPadding">';
          //    PROFILE IMG 
          echo '<img src="'.$row['profile_img'].'" alt=""></img>';

          echo '<div class="caption">';
          //  NAME 
          echo '<h3 class="artistName">'.$row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'].'</h3>';

          echo '<p><a class="button btn btn-primary " id="hello" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-artist="'.$row['last_name'].'">Words</a>';
          echo '</div>';

          echo '</div>';
          echo "</div>";
          // echo "</div>";
          // Modal
          // Modal content

          echo '<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">';
          echo '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">'; 

          echo '<div class="modal-content">';
          echo '<div class="modal-header">';
          echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>';
          // GET NAME FROM DB
          echo '<h4 class="modal-title">'.$row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'].'  </h4>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '<div class="modal-body">';
          echo '<div class=" artistInfo containter-fluid">';
          // LOAD PHP FILE
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '<div class="modal-footer">';
          echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';

          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$(".button").one("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Artists/modal",
      data: ({lastname: $(this).attr("data-artist") }),
      success: function(result){
        $(".artistInfo").append(result);
    }});
});
});
```

**Modal**

```
 <?php  


 for( $i = 0 ; $i < $artist->num_rows() ; $i++ ){
$row = $artist->row_array($i);

echo '<img  class="pull-left img-responsive col-md-8" src=" '.$row['profile_img'].' ">';

echo '<div class="row">';
//    SIDE IMG 
echo '<a href="'.$row['workLink_img1'].'">';
echo '<img id="partsIm "class=" col-sm-4 pull-left img-thumbnail" src="'.$row['work_img1'].'"></img>';
echo '</a>';
//    SIDE IMG 
echo '<a href="'.$row['workLink_img2'].'">';
echo '<img id="partsIm" class="col-sm-4 pull-left img-thumbnail" src="'.$row['work_img2'].'"></img>';
echo '</a>';

//    TEXT
echo '<p style="clear:both">'.$row['text'].'</p> ';
echo '</div>'; 
echo '</div>'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: You used jquery to add/append to the modal, so you will need to clear it on close.

Comment: Why not use `.html(result)` instead of append

Comment: @frz3993 jQuery is still very new to me, I do not understand the difference between the two. Would one load faster than the other.

Comment: I don't think one will load faster than the other, at least it is not noticeable. However ajax will take some time. When you append to an empty class it will add an element to it, the next ajax call will add another below it, and so on. But `.html()` will replace whatever inside the class. I hope you can understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

lets empty it first since ajax can have a time lag...that way any time it takes to get new data it won't be displaying old data:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(){
    $(".artistInfo").empty();// clear old html out
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Artists/modal",
      data: ({lastname: $(this).attr("data-artist") }),
      success: function(result){
        $(".artistInfo").append(result);
    }});
});
```

append() adds to existing html and does not remove it thus you kept adding each time. If element is empty it won't matter what insertion method is used

NOTE: switched to `on()` instead of `one()` which is only intended to be used for a single event

Answer (score 0):

It's in your button click event:

```
$(".button").one("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/Artists/modal",
          data: ({lastname: $(this).attr("data-artist") }),
          success: function(result){
              //you're appending multiple data here
              // $(".artistInfo").append(result);
              // this instead:
              $(".artistInfo").html(result);
          }
          });
    });
});
```